# Ask values with omniorb client

Tags: c++, ubuntu-16.04, omniorb

following a thread in this forum i got the solution for this tutorial: http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/CORBA.html
But now i want to do something more.
I want to do some kind of game, for 2 or more players (clients). But i dont know if omniorb allows me to send values via client program.
The game consist in writing a comment like "throw" on client side and generate a random integer number and if the total sum=>60 wins.
My question basically is if client can catch a keyboard input, and if its more efficient doing all process (generate random and sum) on client or in other class/file.
Like always thank you in advance.
Cheers!

Comment: How corba works is that the client calls a function which looks just like the server's function except that all it does is call the server's function - it's just a proxy for the server's function.  So if you want to send a value you need to call a function.  You could make the function `void throw(int)` and pass a random value or you could make the function `void throw()` and have the server generate the random value (this elimiates people cheating by messing with the client.

Comment: Mmm... i think i understand. So, i build the methods/functions i want on idl file, after doing that i make server/client cpp files using that compiled files from x.idl right? But how can i introduce values, like readln() in client? Like a normal c++ language?

Comment: The IDL contains the functions you want to use.  Then you compile the IDL and it creates C code for the client and the server.  Then on the client you write C++ code that calls the function that came from the IDL and the corresponding function in the server is called through the magic of corba.  Then on the server you need to write the code for what the function does.

Comment: I think I will make an answer...

Comment: Jaja, sorry for that. I will try it too. With example mentioned above i understand a little more about how corba bonded with c++ works. I found out its like sql, with params labeled as in, inout and out. Following the example: 
`module Data
{
interface ServiceA{
   boolean CallServiceRoutineA ( in    long num1,
                                 inout long num2,
                                 out   long retNum );
   boolean CallServiceRoutineB ( inout long num1,
                                 inout long num2);
   };
};`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after a little search i found what i need. Basically i wanted ask for something (string or whatever). Im putting my code, its a cpp file btw.

```
PedidoServicioA peticionA;  // Constructor establishes the link with     the CORBA server.
std::string opcion;
while(opcion!=":salir"){
std::cout << "Introduzca ':lanzar' para tirar el dado o ':salir' para terminar la conexion" << endl;
std::getline(std::cin,opcion);

    if(opcion==":salir"){
    std::cout << "Adios!" << endl;}
    else
    {
    if(peticionA.PedidoServLanzar()!=0) cout << "ServicioA Lanzar: En accion"     << endl;
    if(peticionA.PedidoServSuma()!=0) cout << "ServicioA Sumar: En accion"    << endl;
    }
}
```

Well, as you can see all outputs are in spanish but well is just comments. Thx a lot for your help.
Other thing, can i declare global variables doing OO programing on c++? Coz i cant make an adition, everytime i run it adition value is 0 again.